# ¿Tipos mutables en Java?

Tags: java

Buenas , me gustaría saber que son realmente los Tipos Mutables en Java , ya que no me queda muy claro a veces a la hora de hacer clases.
Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La [respuesta de Ipman1971](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6831/227) es parcialmente correcta. Una clase es mutable cuando permite alterar su estado, esto es, modificar los valores de los campos que contiene, ya sea al hacer sus campos públicos o al proveer métodos que permiten alterar los valores de los campos.

Una clase inmutable no solo no provee métodos que permiten la modificación de su estado, sino que una vez inicializado un objeto de dicha clase, no se puede alterar su estado de ninguna manera. Cualquier operación que resulta en una alteración del estado lo que hace en realidad es devolver un nuevo objeto de la misma clase pero con el estado modificado. Para lograrlo, se deben satisfacer las siguientes condiciones en la definición de la clase:

1. Los campos deben ser declarados como constantes. En el caso de Java, esto se logra al agregar el modificador `final` a los campos.
2. Los campos deben ser a su vez inmutables.
3. Si se deben realizar operaciones sobre la clase para alterar el estado, se deben definir métodos que devuelvan una instancia de la clase en lugar de modificar el estado directamente (lo cual sería "imposible" puesto que los campos están declarados como `final`).

Aquí un ejemplo de una clase inmutable que cumple con todos estos aspectos en cuenta:

```
public class Inmutable {
    //los primitivos son inmutables por defecto
    private final int id;
    //String es una clase inmutable
    private final String nombre;
    //List no se puede saber si es inmutable pero eso tiene arreglo
    //la clase a almacenar en esta lista también debe ser inmutable
    //sino Inmutable no sería del todo inmutable
    private final List<BigDecimal> listaNumeros;
    //En Java, la clase java.util.Date no es inmutable
    //por ende, para trabajar con una fecha en una clase inmutable
    //hay dos opciones: 1) Almacenar el long que representa al tiempo
    //en lugar de almacenar Date. 2) Utilizar clases de un API que provee
    //manejo de fechas para Java como Joda Time o Date and Time disponible
    //desde Java 8 en el paquete java.time
    //Para este caso, utilizaré la opción 1)
    private final long fechaNacimiento;

    //en el constructor se deben inicializar todos los campos
    //ojo: se recibe un como parámetro
    public Inmutable(int id, String nombre, List<BigDecimal> listaNumeros, Date fechaNacimiento) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        //para el caso de la lista, se decora para que sea inmutable
        this.listaNumeros = Collections.unmodifiableList(listaNumeros);
        //en el caso de Date, se almacena solo el valor entero
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento.getTime();
    }

    //se crean getters para acceder a los campos
    //se devuelve el primitivo puesto que no se puede modificar su valor
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    //se devuelve la instancia directamente puesto que no se puede modificar su estado
    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }
    //se puede devolver esta lista puesto que ya es inmutable
    //no hay problema si el cliente intenta modificarla
    //se lanzara una excepción por el comportamiento de la lista
    //devuelta por Collections#unmodifiableList
    public List<BigDecimal> getListaNumeros() {
        return this.listaNumeros;
    }
    //se devuelve una instancia de Date para el cliente de esta clase
    //puesto que esta instancia de Date no está asociada a la clase
    //no importa si el cliente modifica su estado
    public Date getFechaNacimiento() {
        return new Date(fechaNacimiento);
    }

    //se agregan dos operaciones
    //una para agregar valores a la lista de numeros
    //otro para "cambiar" la fecha de nacimiento

    public Inmutable agregaNumero(BigDecimal numero) {
        //preparamos la nueva lista a utilizar
        List<BigDecimal> nuevaListaNumeros = new ArrayList<>(listaNumeros);
        nuevaListaNumeros.add(numero);
        //siempre se crea una nueva instancia a devolver
        //de esta forma la instancia actual no altera su estado
        return new Inmutable(id, nombre, nuevaListaNumeros, new Date(fechaNacimiento));
    }

    public Inmutable setFechaNacimiento(Date fechaNacimiento) {
        return new Inmutable(id, nombre, listaNumeros, fechaNacimiento);
    }
}
```

Comment: Impecable respuesta en especial la técnica de crear una nueva instancia.

Answer (score 5):

Pues creo que lo vas a entender rápidamente, un objeto mutable tiene propiedades que pueden cambiar de valor, para ello la clase tiene métodos que permiten la modificación de las propiedades.

Y un objeto inmutable es aquel que no permite modificar sus propiedades, están son asignadas en su creación y no pueden modificarse. Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
public class Mutable {
  private int id;

  Mutable(int id) {
    this.id=id;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id=id;
  }

}

public class Inmutable {
  //final cumple dos roles
  //1. Forzar que se inicialize el campo 1 sola vez en la clase
  // y que no se le pueda cambiar el valor
  //2. Fuerza que el campo se inicie en el constructor de la clase
  private final int id;

  Inmutable(int id) {
    this.id=id;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

}
```

Comment: En `Inmutable` convendría indicar que el campo `id` debe ser marcado como `final` para asegurar su inmutabilidad

Comment: Exacto , pero solo quería saber sobre Tipos Inmutables. Pero para hacer una clase hay que declarar la clase como final y sus atributos también , a parte de quitar los métodos modificadores.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos!

Comment: @DioniGálvezCamacho si no se marca el campo como `final` significa que puede ser modificado desde dentro de la clase. Si los campos que componen a la clase no son inmutables o no se les marca la inmutabilidad, entonces no puedes decir que tu clase es inmutable.